# Can I leave luggage at or near Kiruna station?

Tags: sweden, luggage-storage, train-stations

We will be travelling through Kiruna in northern Sweden next week and would like to leave a suitcase somewhere during the afternoon before getting the overnight train to Stockholm which leaves at 1834.

I've seen that the [tourist office in Lars Janssonsgatan](https://www.kirunalapland.se/en/faq-frequently-asked-questions/) has a left luggage facility, but it closes at 1600 on a Saturday which is too early.

I can't find anything about station facilities on the SJ website, nor from web searches. Can anyone tell me whether there's a left luggage facility at the station, or somewhere nearby, that would let me drop a case at say 1300 and pick it up at 1800?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer this question from my own experience (September 2018):

- There are luggage lockers in the waiting room at Kiruna station
- As per Johanna's comment, the [opening hours](https://www.dinstation.se/kiruna-station/resor-fragor/) of the station are 05.30 to 21.00, so I expect the lockers may not be accessible outside those times
- They are operated by a 10 Kr coin, which you get back when you open the locker.

The largest locker was slightly too small for our 80 x 50 x 30 cm suitcase (along the 50 cm dimension), so we had to wheel it around with us anyway. However that didn't stop us from going on the LKAB mine tour, as the tour bus driver was happy to stow the case in the bus's luggage compartment.

Comment: We have just used this locker. Coins are no longer needed. Just put in your stuff, close and take the key.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [tourist information](https://www.kirunalapland.se/en/travel-here/train/), there are luggage lockers at the train station:

> The station building is handicap-friendly and there are lockers where
>   you can store your luggage. It is unmanned and no vending machine or
>   supermarket nearby.

I can't find any opening hours for the station itself, but I would be very surprised if the waiting room is not open during normal traffic hours.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't try searching specifically on that site. If it's an unmanned station I expect it would be open at all times, but in any case in time for the evening Stockholm departure. I guess the only missing piece of information is what size the lockers are…

Comment: @nekomatic The station is open from 5.30 to 21.00: https://www.dinstation.se/kiruna-station/resor-fragor/ (in Swedish). There's also an email address and a phone number for further questions about the station.